# Android stops suggesting words

Tags: android, html, mobile

I'm working on a mobile version of the chatroom my website (just a website, not an android application), and the first time I loaded that page on my Motorola DROID everything acted as expected:

1. click on the input field to select it
2. tap the same field again to open up the keyboard
3. start typing
4. auto complete words are suggested gray-on-white right above the keyboard

After a few refreshes of the page step 4 does not happen! There is no white bar above the keyboard, and no suggestions come up.

I cannot figure out what may be causing it, or how to test it. I downloaded Dolphin browser, and the keyboard behaves correctly the first time, but not the following times (just like default).

All suggestions are welcome.

**Edit** Apr 8:
As requested a link to the website: http://phantasyrpg.com will redirect to http://mobile.phantasyrpg.com -- you will need to register and visit the "Tavern" from the menu on top left.

**Edit** Apr 10:
I've created a very empty example that has the same issue:
http://mobile.phantasyrpg.com/test-chat.html I'm also noticing this on other pages as long as the URI is the same -- there's this issue. If there's a GET parameter that's different, suggestions come up correctly.

I'm wondering if there's some setting in my Apache that sends some silly or broken header. But I don't know much about headers.

Comment: are you cleaning the memory after usage ?

Comment: If you mean in Dolphin - even if I check clear cache when exiting, it doesn't work next time I boot Dolphin

Comment: No, I mean in Mobile Application Code.

Comment: This isn't an app it's just a website.

Comment: you mean wap application. I believe its your application problem not a browser's problem.

Comment: What memory cleaning is there in HTML?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser or different phone? I've had similar issues where the keyboard stops giving corrections. Either a restart of my phone or a cache clearing of the particular app would help.

Comment: On my phone the bigger problem is scrolling because that doesn't work properly. ICS 4.0.3.

Comment: Swype gives suggestions normally, only typing doesn't.

Comment: Firefox mobile brings suggestions normally but the typing is generally a bit buggy and end words before it's supposed to. please post a jsfiddle of ther elevant code sections.

Comment: @LoganBibby I tried Dolphin (behaves identically) and Opera Mini (behaves properly)

Comment: I've updated the OP with additional information

Comment: Opera Mini may apply a fix that forces corrections that Dolphin doesn't. Or maybe Dolphin has something in that doesn't work well with keyboards. I wish I could help you better. There's so many variables I'd have to sit down with you to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen before... that are workarounds when using a WebView, but AFAIK there's no way to fix this in just a plain site. But basically, there's some sort of cache or something that exists in the browser tab. At first (new tab) auto-complete always works for me. After staying on the same domain in the same tab for a while, it all crashes. For me specifically, after this point the number '7' on the keyboard will sometimes make the browser segfault =\

If you look around the net, you will notice countless bugs filed for the issues showing up in almost all major websites. All complaining the auto-complete stops on Android. I'm pretty it's global, and unstoppable.

Comment: But using the same browser I don't have these issues on, say, google.com. Keep in mind I didn't develop a browser, just a mobile-friendly website.